# Alan Storm "helloworld" config.xml file

Tags: magento

I am having trouble following this tutorial.  Below is my configuration file. Do I have the frontend section in the correct place? I can't seem to get this to work. I got to my site `/helloworld/index/index`, and nothing happens.  What is supposed to happen?

app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Hellowowrld/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
    </modules>
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>

</config>
```

app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php:

```
class Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello Index!';
    }
}
```

app/etc/modules/Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Indenting your code samples on Stack Overflow will make sure they're formatted correctly.  The module allows you to load a URL that prints hello world when you access the URL http://magento.example.com/helloworld. Something always happens, but not what you expect. Describe your expectations vs. what actually happened and people will be able to help you.

Comment: I removed the "storm" tag from this question, but for the record Alan, it must be nice to have your own tag :)

Comment: @joseph mastey  Not if I have to share it with a piece of crap phone http://stackoverflow.com/tags/storm

Answer (score 2):

What version of Magento are you running? I'm not sure whats wrong other then a cache issue.  I have taken your files and they work great on 1.4.0.1 (other then the typo in the path to your config.xml unless thats not a typo)

Here is what I have that worked:

app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Helloworld/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello Index!';
    }
}
```

app/etc/modules/Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Soo yeah basically the same thing ... have you tried turning cache completely off?

Answer (score 0):

You could try two solutions:

1) refresh the cache of Magento and try to reload the page

2) change the  tag right below  tag with  (and refresh your cache)

Comment: Question, change the tag right below tag with???? with what please? I have refreshed cache many times. Thanks